# How to authenticate with Firebase via service account key?

Tags: firebase, gcloud

I'm trying to understand how to authenticate on the firebase-cli via service account key.

I downloaded a service account key via my admin console, and managed to successfully authenticate via gcloud-cli:

```
➜ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-service-key.json         
Activated service account credentials for: [firebase- adminxxx0@xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

When I try to fetch the projects, it fails:

```
➜ firebase projects:list
✖ Preparing the list of your Firebase projects

Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.

Having trouble? Try again or contact support with contents of firebase-debug.log
```

and when I visit my log file:

```
[debug] [2022-11-01T15:16:35.589Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
```

Am I missing something?

TIA.

**EDIT:**
The service account provided by the Firebase SDK has the following permissions:

```
Firebase Admin
Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent
Service Account Token Creator
```

Comment: The log file error explains the permissions required. Edit your question and show the project IAM bindings for this service account.

Comment: I'm using the Firebase admin SDK service account generated from the firebase admin console.
Where else could I find the information helpful to solving this problem?

Comment: Using the SDK is one step. The other is to grant the service account permissions. Which permissions did you assign? https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/

Comment: Added info to the post.

Comment: For the scope **cloudplatformprojects.readonly** add the IAM role **roles/browser**. The error message can be confusing as it lists the scopes you need but not the ones you are missing.